# Are there any countries with restrictions on the usage of religious names in certain contexts?

Tags: law, religion

An example of such context(s) would be usage of religious names in computer/mobile apps or in dictionaries.

Comment: Some countries have restrictions against using religious names as trademarks. Some have restrictions on how a name may be used (blasphemy). If a name cannot be printed in a dictionary, then I don't see how it could be printed in a law that would impose the restriction, More clarity is needed to identify the context.

Comment: Are you looking for specific legal advice?

Comment: Voted to close as question is broad - please edit and add more details and citin other online resources that didn't help you. (Note that even if there are no such legal  restrictions, cultural aspects also needs to be considered - there was a huge outcry in India when some [Hindu Gods images was used in an inner wear garment](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/hindu-gods-on-underwear-orissa-writes-to-us-embassy/articleshow/2639180.cms). While India doesn't have any law prohibiting such uses, other laws could be interpreted culturally to make such things a criminal act).

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* Don't worry if your question is closed at first, you may have to do some editing to better fit the site before it's reopened - happens to all of us. Of course there are plenty of laws in counties that align strongly with single religions or that have groups that identify with different religions that have a history nof not getting along. "What are some examples of..." is not a good fit to Stack Exchange because 1) "list questions" don't have the possibility of a single correct answer, and 2) as sfxedit points out, it's just too broad. Can you narrow down further?

Comment: Try also to add some evidence of research as well, Folks are more likely to generate an answer if the question is more than "Can someone look this up for me?"